# What is the Correct way to pass parameters in function

Tags: shortcode, wpdb

I'm using the following code and calling the function from the page. It is not responding.

```
add_shortcode('my_ttcode', 'create_my_shortcode');
function create_my_shortcode($key1, $key2){
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb -> get_results ( "
    SELECT * 
    FROM wp_villageleaderdb 
    WHERE VillageID = $key1 AND VillageLeaderPosition = $key2 LIMIT 0, 100
    ", 'ARRAY_N' );
var_dump($result);  
//return $result[0][1] . "<br />";  $data = '';
$i = 0;
foreach( $result as $single_result ){
$data .= $result[$i][1] . "<br />";
$i++;
}
```

Instead of $key1 and $key2 if the values are given, it is working ok.

The calling from the wordpress page is

```
[my_ttcode (V001, Sarpanch)]
```

What is the correct way?

I have tried but the parameter is not getting passed. here is the code.

```
 add_shortcode('vill_problems', 'get_villageproblems');
 function get_villageproblems($atts){ 
 extract(shortcode_atts( array( 'villid' => "V000", ), $atts ));
 global $wpdb;
 $result = $wpdb -> get_results ( "
 SELECT *
 FROM wp_villageleaderdb
 WHERE VillageID = $villid LIMIT 0, 100
 ", 'ARRAY_N' );

 $i = 0;
 foreach( $result as $single_result ){
 $data .= $result[$i][1] . "<br />"; $i++;
 }
 return $data . "<br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is problematic in the OP's code snippet:

- Missing [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) for default attribute handling.
- Incorrectly defining the shortcode's input argument, use instead function `create_my_shortcode( $attr = [], $content = null ){ ... }`
- Not escaping user input, check e.g. [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/). We want to avoid possible SQL injections.
- Uses hardcoded *table prefix*, `wp_`, instead of `$wpdb->prefix`.
- Fetches all fields with `SELECT *`. Better to fetch only what's needed.
- Not returning the output from the shortcode's callback.
- Incorrectly setting the shortcode's attributes, should be called from the content with e.g. `[my_ttcode  key1="V001" key2="Sarpanch"]` but use better descriptive attributes instead of `key1` and `key2`.
- Maybe not using `WP_DEBUG`, when developing, as there would be PHP notices from eg. not initializing the `$data` string before appending to it.
- Not indenting the code properly, makes it harder to maintain and understand code projects.

Check e.g. the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for more general info on [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1. Someone told me codex is deprecated. Glad to see you disagree :)

Comment: hehe, it's true about the reference on functions/hooks/classess etc, but I'm not sure the longer articles, like the one on the Shortcodes API, have been relocated to a newer doc home on wordpress.org, so I linked to the old Codex page in the meanwhile ;-) Also the API links on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/ still point to the old Codex.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was unable to bring these into. Most of the info is very cryptic for me. Can you pl give a simple example

Comment: You're welcome @SriramNadiminti - did you check out the Codex article for general info?

Comment: I have tried but the parameter is not getting passed. here is the code.  <code>   add_shortcode('vill_problems', 'get_villageproblems');
function get_villageproblems($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
 'villid' => "V000",
 ), $atts ));
 global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb -> get_results ( "
        SELECT * 
        FROM wp_villageleaderdb 
  WHERE VillageID = $villid LIMIT 0, 100
        ", 'ARRAY_N' );
 $i = 0;
foreach( $result as $single_result ){
 $data .= $result[$i][1] . "<br />";
 $i++;
}
return $data . "<br />";
}

Comment: Please make an edit to your current question, it's very hard to read the code in comments, thanks.